# Preserve number of results at different stages of mongo query?

Tags: mongodb, pagination

In a multi-tenant database, there are basically two important degrees of $matching. First, you want to only show the user items from their tenant. If you were to tell the user a total count of documents, you'd certainly only want to count *their* items. Second, when allowing the user to search their documents, you'd want to be able to show them the total number of documents matching their query. When an API is paginated, you won't return every result, so the application can't simply count the results returned, as mongo is told to limit the output. How do we preserve these counts at different stages through the pipeline?

e.g. event data:

```
{ id: 1, tenant: 1, name: "Device online", level: "info", /* ... */ },
{ id: 2, tenant: 1, name: "Device offline", level: "warning", /* ... */ },
{ id: 3, tenant: 1, name: "System failure", level: "error", /* ... */ },
{ id: 4, tenant: 2, name: "Device online", level: "info", /* ... */ },
{ id: 5, tenant: 2, name: "Device online", level: "info", /* ... */ },
{ id: 6, tenant: 2, name: "Device online", level: "info", /* ... */ },
{ id: 7, tenant: 1, name: "Device online", level: "info", /* ... */ },
{ id: 8, tenant: 2, name: "Device offline", level: "warning", /* ... */ },
{ id: 9, tenant: 1, name: "Device online", level: "info", /* ... */ },
{ id: 10, tenant: 1, name: "Device online", level: "info", /* ... */ },
{ id: 11, tenant: 2, name: "Device online", level: "info", /* ... */ },
{ id: 12, tenant: 1, name: "Device online", level: "info", /* ... */ },
{ id: 13, tenant: 1, name: "Device online", level: "info", /* ... */ },
...
```

So if we had a pipeline like

```
[
    { $match: { tenant: "1" } }, // get stage output count for total documents
    { $match: { level: "info" } }, // get stage output count for queried documents
    { $sort: { timestamp: -1 } },
    { $skip: 15 },
    { $limit: 5 },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            let: { id: "$actorId" },
            pipeline: [ $project: { id: 1, name: 1, email: 1 } ],
            as: "user",
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$user",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        }
    }
]
```

**How could we extract and return the document counts output from the first 2 stages (or input to stages 2 and 3)?**

I've looked at various uses of $group and $facet but not sure if those are usable. $facet also claims it ignores all indexes, so that's basically out. I've also looked at explain results, but they don't seem to return the exact info I need, or I'm not looking in the right place. I imagine it's doing the pretty trivial optimization for the above type of query, so the explain results don't exactly match the stages. This seems like it would be really easy, but the way to do it in mongo is eluding me. In addition, imagine the $lookup could be done earlier and used in matching as well.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to conceptualize the use case here and I imagine it's part of some sort of notification system for the users who have email subscriptions to certain types of events.  Looking at your pipeline, I see `"$actorId"` but I don't see that in the event data collection, nor do I see it used in the `"$lookup"`.  What is `"actorId"`? I also don't see `"timestamp"` in the event data.  For the example shown, are you trying to `"$lookup"` the users who have a subscription to `"info"` level events on `"tenant": 1`?

Comment: ... or maybe `"actorId"` _is_ in the event data and caused the event? ... and `"actorId"` corresponds to some `"_id"`/`"id"` in the `users` collection?

Comment: Sorry, yes I was trying to keep the items brief, there would be even more fields than that for an event/notification system. Actor does refer to the user causing the event. I may have switched up the lookup field? Either way, again, point being carrying on the count data from earlier stages, through some later stages. It would be awesome if we could cache certain stage facts to metadata or something like document count or exec time or something

Comment: I can show aggregation pipelines using `"$facet"` and/or `"$group"` to produce the results you seek in a single pipeline, but it seems you've already evaluated pipelines like these and they are not ideal.  Depending on your collections, etc., perhaps separate queries will be more performant.  You may need to compare time measurements to determine what works best for you.

Comment: I appreciate your time. I just posted a pipeline that seems to work and would love your analysis and potential improvements. And uglier output is ok as long as it's more performant.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do it, though I'm not sure of the performance.

```
[
    {
        // Initial match excluding what user can never see
        $match: {
            tenant: "1"
        },
    },
    {
        // Get total count while preserving documents in `data`
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            data: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
            totalCount: { $sum: 1 }
        },
    },
    {
        // Preserve total count. Filter data for user's query
        // (Not necessary if user has no additional query)
        $project: {
            totalCount: 1,
            data: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$$ROOT.data",
                    as: "document",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: [ "$document.level", "info" ],
                    }
            },
            }
        },
    },
    {
        // Preserve total count. Sort data based on user's query. Sort just what
        // will be returned, but before pagination
        $project: {
            totalCount: 1,
            data: {
                $sortArray: {
                    input: "$$ROOT.data",
                    sortBy: { timestamp: -1 }
                }
            }
        },
    },
    {
        // Preserve total count. Paginate before returning. But save the 
        // match count first (can match total count if no user query)
        $project: {
            totalCount: 1,
            data: { $slice: ["$$ROOT.data", 15, 5] },
            matchCount: { $size: "$$ROOT.data" }
        }
    }
]
```

Some steps can be omitted if user does not have a custom query or sort. I have my worries that 1. indexing could go unused after the grouping stage (this would mean the second $filter and the $sortArray would be much less efficient) and 2. It's not clear if $slice has any performance issues since $limit and $skip are normally used. But $facet, which admits to not using indexes, was avoided successfully. And apologies, but $sortArray is version 5.2+. If you have an earlier version, you'd have to sort before the grouping, potentially sorting more than necessary.

Some details that made this solution less confusing:

- Think of each document being fed individually into each stage. `$$ROOT` is not the list of all documents, but each document at a time.
- ^This means that the first stage outputs all of the valid documents, and each stage after $group is actually only seeing a single document. After the second stage, all of those documents are in $$ROOT.data, we just hope they retain some index information for the following stages. Will need to look further if that's the case.

Comment: It's even possible that a user that can manage tenants wouldn't need the first stage, as they could see documents across all tenants. So much of this is variable based on the user's needs.

Comment: Just some thoughts ... Could `"$$ROOT.data"` just be `"$data"`?  Could you skip the first `"$project"` by changing the first `"$group"` with `"data": {"$push": {"$cond": [{$eq: [ "$document.level", "info" ]}, "$$ROOT", "$$REMOVE"]}}`?

Comment: Oops, too much copy/paste ... `"data": {"$push": {"$cond": [{$eq: [ "$level", "info" ]}, "$$ROOT", "$$REMOVE"]}}`  [I think.]

Comment: Nice, yea good catch